# No IUserTokenProvider is registered for self hosted webapi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I am currently using asp.net identity for identity management, IdentityServer3 for oauth2, Castle Windosr for IOC and the DataProtectorTokenProvider for email tokens. My code works fine when hosted in IIS but I get the error No IUserTokenProvider is registered when self hosted within a windows service. My startup code is:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; private set; }
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
        var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        ioc = new IoC();
        app.UseIdentityAdministration(ioc);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
    }
}
```

In my user controller, the constructor has this code:

```
        var dataProtectorProvider = Startup.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectorProvider != null)
        {
            var dataProtector = dataProtectorProvider.Create(RC.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose, RC.ConfirmEmailTokenPurpose);
            _userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser, int>(dataProtector)
                {
                    TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SC.TokenLifespan)
                };
        }
```

_userManager is the Asp.net identity user manager and is provide by IOC. It all works fine when hosted in IIS but when self hosted i.e.

```
internal void StartService()
{
    var options = new StartOptions();
    options.Urls.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublicOrigin"]);

    webApp = WebApp.Start(options, builder => new Startup().Configuration(builder));
}
```

I get the above error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.